# Windows 7 force reboots when running TightVNC server

Tags: windows-7, vnc

So I recently got a new computer running Windows 7, installed the latest version of TightVNC Server (not as a service, just a standalone app that runs on startup).

I'm logging in via an XP box, using the most recent version of the TightVNC client. The login process itself works smoothly, and I can use the computer remotely... for a while. After variable length of time (30 minutes to 2 hours, roughly), the VNC window stops updating, then closes as the computer reboots. Specifically, it drops a socket error message.

After the computer's rebooted, I can connect to the server, but after authentication, VNC freezes in the middle of the initial refresh, then disconnects as the server reboots again.

General advice or suggestions?

Additional info:

After restarting, it does display the 'Windows has encountered an error and had to restart, would you like to let MS know?' window; if I expand the 'More Info' thing on the bottom, I get:

Problem Event Name: BlueScreen 
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.768.3 
Locale ID: 1033

plus a bit more identification data that I just lost.

Comment: Our school uses TightVNC on Windows XP.  It doesn't work well.  It makes the computer run slow or freeze, so I think that it is a problem with TightVNC in general.  Try some other software.

Comment: I've had good results with TightVNC; I used it on my old XP box at home with almost nothing in the way of problems for two-three years, save some fiddling with ports on my router.

Comment: Turn on error reporting, disable the reboot on error, and see if the machine blue-screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) or [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Haven't tried RealVNC; did install UltraVNC, but it died on me after about two hours and I haven't been able to reconnect in.

Comment: Got home, found out that it hadn't restarted. This looks like it might be a more workable solution. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent.  As specified in Andrei's reply tunneling VNC through SSH is a good idea as VNC is completely unsecured.  CopSSH has worked very well for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

There was a known problem with the previous version (1.1.68) of DFMirage Driver used by TightVNC on Vista/7. You need to make sure that you installed the latest DFMirage (2.0.105 currently). You can find the most recent version here:

http://www.demoforge.com/dfmirage.htm

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid VNC as it seems too slow for me.

I'd recommend CopSSH + Tunnelier or TeamViewer (portablapps.org)

Comment: The slowdown isn't an issue for me. Have you run Teamviewer in a Win7 environment?